# How exactly to use array.where?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I'm not sure if I got the right idea of how **array.where()** works.
I've got an array filled with Spectrum.cs objects. each spectrum contains a filename-property.

mySpectrum.filename; //String

Now I have a stringvalue that I want to compare with each object in the array to find out, whether it has the same filename. As I got it it should work like this:

```
Spectrum bgSpec = new Spectrum(); //Has a filename
Spectrum[] currentSpectra;  //Array filled with Spectra

//Somehow this doesn't seem to work. Propably due to the returnvalue for where() which seems //to be IEnumerable.
Spectrum tempSpectrum = currentSpectra.Where<Spectrum>(c => c.filename == bgSpec);
```

I propably got everything wrong and would be very grateful if somebody could point out what it is or how to do it right.

Thanks in advance,
BC++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a *single* value meeting that criterion. So maybe use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx):

```
var tempSpectrum = currentSpectra.Single(c => c.filename == bgSpec.filename);
```

Other options:

- [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx)
- [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx)
- [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx)
- [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx)
- [`LastOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.lastordefault.aspx)

The `OrDefault` versions will return `null` if there's no matching element. The difference between `First`, `Single` and `Last` is in terms of the result for multiple matches: `Single` will throw an exception, whereas `First` or `Last` will take the first or last match respectively.

Which of these is most appropriate will depend on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: You are comparing filename (probably string) with Spectrum object

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Yup, fixed that bit. (I'd assumed the predicate itself was okay.)

Answer (score 4):

`Where` narrows down the input sequence to a subset. That's not exactly what you want here, which is probably more like

```
var tempSpectrum = currentSpectra
                   .SingleOrDefault(c => c.filename == bgSpec.Filename);
```

`SingleOrDefault` will return either the `Spectrum` instance your are looking for or (assuming `Spectrum` is a reference type) `null` if no such spectrum exists. It will also throw an exception if there are multiple spectra that match the search parameter.

If this is not exactly what you want, look also into `Single` and `First`/`FirstOrDefault`.

There are also non-LINQ alternatives to most of these: [`Array.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9hy2xwa) and several more static `Array.FindX` methods.

Answer (score 2):

As John said, `Single` is appropriate here. If you are have several spectrum objects, which could match condition, then you should use list of spectrum objects instead. Also you should compare `filename` properties

```
IEnumerable<Spectrum> tempSpectrums = currentSpectra.Where(c => c.filename == bgSpec.filename);
Spectrum tempSpectrum = currentSpectra.SingleOrDefault(c => c.filename == bgSpec.filename);
```

Also keep in mind, that you don't need to specify generic type for such methods like `Where`, `Single`, `SingleOrDefault` - type will be inferred by compiler from collection type.

Comment: Can't see how that's going to compile... you're still assigning an `IEnumerable<Spectrum>` to a `Spectrum` variable. (Downvote removed now it's been fixed.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yep, fixed that (I didn't notice resulting value since question was about Where condition) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` in your `LINQ` instead of `Where`

```
var tempSpectrum = currentSpectra.SingleOrDefault(c => c.filename == bgSpec.filename);
```